# Error: Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now

Tags: android-studio

I got an error in the execution of the app, how can I solve this?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

 android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    api 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    api project(':mobicomkit')//Note: use this for customization
    //api 'com.applozic.communication.message:mobicomkit:5.8.2' 
    implementation 'com.daprlabs.aaron:cardstack:0.3.1-beta0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    compile 'ai.api:sdk:2.0.7@aar'
    compile 'ai.api:libai:1.4.8'
}
```

I got the error below:

> Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following
>   dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation
>   processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
>       - log4j-core-2.2.jar (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.2)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in dependencies.

```
annotationProcessor 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.2'
```

For more information: [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration?utm_source=android-studio#annotationProcessor_config)